# cucumber not able to pass a list into an object

Tags: java, cucumber

How can I pass a list into an object:

My class is as follows:

```
public class Person {

private Integer personId;

private List<String> hobbies;

}
```

Below is my feature file:

```
Given I have the following people:
  | personId | hobbies                 | 
  |        1 | {'football', 'painting'}|
```

In my given method, the personId is being populated but my hobbies field is empty, what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Without creating a new step specifically for associating hobbies with a person, I would just split the hobbies on `", "` in your step definition:

```
Given I have the following people:
    | personId | hobbies            |
    | 1        | football, painting |
```

This is nice and readable, yet the step definition logic would not be too complicated.